# System of equations to solve a word problem on two rates of pay for extended leave

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have 100 nominal dollars of pay owed to me as paid leave.

I have 71 days over which this $100 could be paid in equal installments as 'full pay'.

I have 142 days over which this $100 could be paid in equal installments as 'half pay'.

I wish to take 95 days of leave.

I wish to avoid any days of zero pay.

I wish to expend all the available leave in my 95 days of leave, both in terms of time and in terms of dollars. Remnant leave after 95 days may not be recoverable either in further time or dollars.

What is the maximum number of days I can take at full pay and the minimum of days I can take at half pay in a total leave period of 95 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this algebraically, consider you taking $x$ days of leave on full pay and $y$ days of leave on half pay.

Now there are 2 conditions: You want to take $95$ days of leave alltogether, so

$$x+y=95 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

and you want your leave to account for the equvalent of $71$ fully paid days

$$x+\frac12y=71.\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

There are multiple ways to solve that system of equations, one possibility is to subtract \eqref{eq2} from \eqref{eq1}, which yields

$$\frac12y=95-71=24$$

and therefore

$$y=48.$$

Together with \eqref{eq1} that means

$$x=95-48=47$$

which is the solution you got as well.

The solution by Ross uses basically the same argument, just without the equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you take full pay you run out in $71$ days.  Each full pay day can be converted to two half pay days, adding one paid day, and you are $24$ days short, so convert $24$ full pay days to $48$ half pay days.  You have $47$ full pay days left, for $95$ in total.

Comment: Your answer led me to work out a numerical solution on a spreadsheet which is very crude. But it gave me the optimal answer of 47 days full pay and 48 days half pay. I am still curious, how can this be expressed algebraically and/or by using calculus?

Comment: @Ross: You seem to have mixed up the total number of leave days (95) witht the money amount (100), leading to an incorrect solution.

Comment: @mjl2009:  you are right, I confused the number of days.  Algebraically, if you have $f$ full pay days and $h$ half pay days, the equations are $h+f=95, h+f/2=71$.  Solve them simultaneously.  If you subtract them, you get $f/2=24$, which looks like my answer.

Comment: Thanks Ross for the clarification and Ingix for the algebraic working.